# solr 5.0 With Jetty 9 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, webserver, solr

Running Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 and Solr-5.1.0. in a production environment. I followed [these instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Taking+Solr+to+Production) to install Solr, but I can`t access it.

I have the following issues:

1. In a browser, when I access the Solr server, it displays the following error:

   ```
   HTTP ERROR: 404
   Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:
       Not Found
   Powered by Jetty://
   ```
2. I don’t know whether the Solr service is running or not, because I don't know how to get the Solr service status.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: @rajiv: If you log in, before you edit your own question, the changes are applied immediately and don't need to go through review.

Comment: You need to check your jetty logs first.  It should explain the 404.  the exact call you are making is unclear too.  how do you access it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue. switched java version from 8 to 7 ,started working without any issue.